# Removing "outer rows" to allow for interpolation (and prevent extrapolation)

Tags: r, dplyr, interpolation, rows

I have (left)joined two data frames by country-year.

```
df<- left_join(df, df2, by="country-year")
```

leading to the following example output:

```
   country country-year    a     b
1  France  France2000        NA    NA 
2  France  France2001      1000  1000  
3  France  France2002        NA    NA
4  France  France2003      1600  2200
5  France  France2004        NA    NA
6  UK          UK2000      1000  1000  
7  UK          UK2001        NA    NA
8  UK          UK2002      1000  1000  
9  UK          UK2003        NA    NA
10 UK          UK2004        NA    NA
```

I initially wanted to remove all values for which both of the added columns (a,b) were NA.

```
df<-df[!is.na( df$a | df$b ),]
```

However, in second instance, I decided I wanted to interpolate the data I had (but not extrapolate). So instead I would like to remove all the columns for which I cannot interpolate; in the example:

```
1  France  France2000        NA    NA
5  France  France2004        NA    NA
9  UK          UK2003        NA    NA
10 UK          UK2004        NA    NA
```

I believe there are 2 options. First I somehow adapt this function:

```
library(tidyerse)
TRcomplete<-TRcomplete%>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate_at(a:b,~na.fill(.x,"extend"))
```

to interpolate only, and then remove then apply `df<-df[!is.na( df$a | df$b ),]`

or I write a code to remove the "outer"columns first and then use `extend` like normal. Desired output:

```
   country country-year    a     b 
2  France  France2001      1000  1000  
3  France  France2002      1300  1600
4  France  France2003      1600  2200
6  UK          UK2000      1000  1000  
7  UK          UK2001         0     0
8  UK          UK2002      1000  1000
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are options in na.fill to specify what is done.  If you look at `?na.fill`, you see that fill can specify the left, interior and right, so if you specify the left and right are `NA` and the interior is `"extend"`, then it will only fill the interior data.  You can then `filter` the rows with `NA`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)
df %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(a:b),~na.fill(.x,c(NA, "extend", NA))) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(a) | !is.na(b))
```

By the way, you have a typo in your `library(tidyverse)` statement; you are missing the v.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you help me out just a little bit with what the `(.x,c(NA, "extend", NA))` does exactly? I assume the filter in this case is similar to my `df<-df[!is.na( df$a | df$b ),]` part?

Comment: I edited my answer to explain what the arguments for fill are.  Yes, the filter is similar to the subset command you used.

Comment: `na.fill(X, list(NULL, "extend", NULL))` would **drop** the externior NA values and use linear interpolation on the internior ones.  `na.fill(X, c(NA, "extend", NA))` would **retain** exterior NAs while using linear interpolation on interior ones.

Comment: @Kerry Jackson Thank you so much for explaining. I keep getting the following error: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column a can't be converted from numeric to character` when I apply this code. Do you have any idea what could be the cause of this? I checked but Column `a` is numerical column with only numbers or NA's.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why you are getting that error.  I know you said you checked, but what do you get from `str(df)`?  I get `str(df)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ country     : chr  "France" "France" "France" "France" ...
 $ country-year: chr  "France2000" "France2001" "France2002" "France2003" ...
 $ a           : int  NA 1000 NA 1600 NA 1000 NA 1000 NA NA
 $ b           : int  NA 1000 NA 2200 NA 1000 NA 1000 NA NA`

Comment: Mine gives `Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 6984 obs. of  73 variables:` This is on the actual df. It has 11 "character", 2 "labelled" and 60 "numeric" (among which a,b)

Comment: Can you try subsetting the data to just a small number of rows/columns and seeing if you get the same error.  If so, try editing the question to include that data using the `dput` command.  If not, try including more rows/columns until the error repeats.

Comment: @Kerry Jackson I have figured out that it is the `group_by(country) %>%` part that subsequently causes the issue. Without grouping the function works fine (but regretfully does not do what I want).  Only grouping is not a problem either. I was wondering if it was possibly the issue that some countries did not have two points, but have not been able to figure out how to adapt the code to make it skip these countries.